# jQuery when document is loaded, check each 3 sec and reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var el = $('#solving');    
    setInterval(function(){
      if (el.text() == 'gotta!...'){
        location.reload();
      }
    },3000);
  });
```

and i want to do, that after my page is loaded, every 3 seconds i check my html page, on presenting of text 'gotta!...', and if present, i must refresh this page, but for some reasons it didn't work. What i do wrong?

How to check page on presenting of some text (with timer), and reload it?

Comment: What kind of element is `#solving`?

Comment: who is injecting the text into the el to start with?

Comment: @KevinB I think that when set interval executes that anonymous function it might be out of scope.

Comment: Run a `console.log(el.text())` right before your `if`, what's the log say?

Comment: @AlexW i think not, http://jsfiddle.net/txC5V/

Comment: However, your (now deleted) answer would solve another possible problem if #solving was dynamically added later.

Comment: #solving is a div, console.log(el.text()) before if nothing say, just before timer: gotta!...

Comment: it should be working. check -> http://jsfiddle.net/ULTux/ . the problem might come from some other place.

Comment: Possible whitespace issue, try trimming the text then comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following example or the jsbin(http://jsbin.com/ibOmaSu/3/edit):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var el = $('#solving');    
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Checking if el has text");
    if (el.text() == 'gotta!...'){
      console.log("Reloading");
      location.reload();
    }
  },3000);

// This will simulate whatever adds text to el
setTimeout(function() {
  el.text('gotta!...');
},10000);  
});
```

Small note: I can only imagine that the `location.reload` will not work in www.jsbin.com because it's caught and interrupted, so test locally. I've added a `console.log` to prove that it hits the correct code line.

Comment: Here's [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHumZ/) for your answer (for those who prefer over jsBin)

Comment: i copy your code, and every 10sec page is automatically reloaded, with log Checking if el has text , seems that works good

Comment: but what do you mean with // This will simulate whatever adds text to el, do i need this part

Comment: and do i need my if (el.text() == 'Ожидайте появления новой капчи!...'){   now?

Comment: that's just for testing, I don't know how you want to add the test gotta in there, you can replace that bit for anything else. If the code solved your issue, please marked as correct answer.

Comment: hm, i have tested it normally now, and i see that even if page didn't contain it, it's reload! i try also if ($('#solving:contains("Wait!")')){  and it's reloading